# open webview links in external browser

Tags: android, webview

How do I make apps which use WebView to render my website to open links  in default browser ?

For example; I click on link to my website inside a mail which I read using Gmail, Gmail renders my website inside WebView and does the same for each link I click inside my website and do not suggest to open default browser

target="_blank" did not work

Am I depended on app's developer implementation or there is an html attribute magic ? they must override 
WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading ?

Comment: The decision of how to handle links is up to the app (in this case, Gmail) and possibly the user (if the app allows configuration of this behavior). You do not get a vote.

Comment: @CommonsWare I do not deserve a vote, why comment and not answer ?

Comment: My guess is that you are looking for some hack. Such a hack will not be reliable, as you have no way of knowing what the app is doing. For example, it might be rewriting the HTML to suit its needs, breaking your hack. But, it would not surprise me if there is some hack (HTML or JS) that works for some apps.

Comment: precisely, its for CTF and I have the tools to monitor if it works

Answer (score -1):

Very simple. Attached a `WebViewClient` to your WebView, and override the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function. In the fuction, check URL, if you want the WebView to handle it, return false, otherwise create an intent to launch browser, and return true.

Comment: Wrote that in my question, I cannot add java code into the app because it is not my app

Comment: @IddoE Sorry, I read the qu still to quickly. As for the question, Google Sign-in does prevent signins from WebViews, so there must be a way to detect a WebView, and notify user. But that is probably not what you want.